# Gradient text with partial underline using CSS

Tags: css, gradient, underline

I'm trying to achieve the style in the image below using CSS. I've seen other similar questions, however, they either only have gradient on the underline, or underline the entire text. I want to be able to only underline some of the words. The little space in the underline between the words is also needed. How should I go about this?

My HTML:

```
<h1 class="hero-text">
    Some text<br>
    some more text<br>
    <span>Underline</span> <span>Here</span>.
</h1>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you will always have a dark background you can try the following:

```css
h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  position: relative;
  color:#fff; /* white here */
  background: #242420; /* dark background here */
  width: fit-content; /* not mandatory */
}
h1 span {
  text-decoration: underline;
} 

h1::before {
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  inset:0;
  background: linear-gradient(-45deg,#fc8329,#5dc4a7); /* gradient */
  mix-blend-mode: darken; /* the magic trick */
}

body {
  background: #242420; /* same as h1 background */
}
```

```html
<h1 class="hero-text">
    Some text<br>
    some more text<br>
    <span>Underline</span> <span>Here</span>.
</h1>
```

Comment: Thank you, this works. However, the text loses some of its quality. It appears to be a tiny bit thicker and less smooth. Any ideas for how this could be solved?